# моя рекурсивная функция возвращает None

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, рекурсия

не могу понять в чем дело. Сделал функцию, которая переводит число из десятичной системы исчисления в n-ую, но возникла проблема:

В данном случае функция отрабатывает хорошо

```
def converter(n, ns, result = ""):
    if n <= 0:
        return print(result)
    converter(n // ns, ns, str(n % ns) + result)       
converter(8, 2)
```

А в этом случае возвращается None

```
def converter(n, ns, result = ""):
    if n <= 0:
        return result
    converter(n // ns, ns, str(n % ns) + result)       
print(converter(8, 2))
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: `return print(result)` свидетельствует что вы плохо понимаете как работает язык.

Comment: Что возвращает ваша функция если *n > 0*?

Answer (score 1):

В рекурсивной функции `return` должен быть как минимум два раза. Один раз там, где рекурсия заканчивается, один раз там, где рекурсия вызывается.

Comment: Это не совсем так. Скорее надо сказать что `return` нельзя опускать, как это сделал автор вопроса.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy так это то же самое, только другими словами

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
def converter(n, ns, result=""):
    if n <= 0:
        return result
    return converter(n // ns, ns, str(n % ns) + result)

print(converter(8, 2))
```

Comment: спасибо, сработадо!

Answer (score 0):

У вас в-принципе неправильная идея использования рекурсивной функции, я считаю, что параметр result лишний

```
def converter(n, ns):
    if n <= 0:
        return ""
    else:
        return converter(n // ns, ns) + str(n % ns)        
print(converter(8, 2))
```

Comment: `else` после `return` нецелесообразен

Comment: Есть два вида рекурсивных вычислений: вычисления на параметре (у автора вопроса) и вычисление на результате (у вас). Эти два метода не лучше и не хуже друг друга. Более того, вычисление на параметре разрешает оптимизацию хвостовой рекурсии. В языках где она есть рекурсию предпочитают делать на параметрах. Любую линейную рекурсию (не больше одного рекурсивного вызова в теле функции) можно переписать и так и так.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за ответ. Есть статьи где можно с этим ознакомиться? Хочу получше понять идею почему так. В моем понимании рекурсия с параметром занимала бы больше места в памяти, относительно рекурсии при вычислении на результате

Comment: Именно что наоборот. Найдите в сети SICP ("Структура и интерпретация компьютерных программ"). Если не найдёте, стукните мне я поделюсь копией. Там несколько первых глав, для погружения в основы достаточно.